# 24bit USB Sample Rate Support

Tags: windows, audio, usb, driver, usb-descriptor

My question is quite similar to this question: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541589/usb-24bits-audiostream-descriptors), but i am not allowed to comment.

I'm implementing a PIC32 as a soundcard, and i now have a working USB audio stream, supporting  16-bit at 32kHz and 48kHz sample rates. I now want to change the bit depth to 24-bit, so i change my USB Descriptors to:

```
bSubFrameSize  = 0x03,    // 3 bytes per sample
bBitResolution = 0x18,    // 24-bit resolution
```

When i do this, he bit resolution is changed as it is suppose to, but in the properties of the microphone, the dropdown menu where i could change the sampling frequency is grey.
I havn't changed anything in the endpoint descriptors, where both 32kHz and 48kHz still is supported.

[image: can't change sampling frequency]

My USB topology has 1 Audio control interface with a couple of Units, and 2 Audio Streaming Interfaces, for streaming IN and OUT. 
Marc O answered his question by saying that something in his Input Terminal, i have tried changing `wChannelConfig` but i doesn't work.
I have tried Uninstalling and Installing the device drivers, but doesn't work.

**What more do i need to change in the descriptors, to be able to select the sampling Frequency?**

Thanks :)

**Edit: Added Descriptor code and descriped progress**

When i changed the no of channels to 2, and made the `wChannelConfig = 0x03 -> right + Left Front`, i saw the the field on he picture change to: "2 channel, 24 bit, 48000 Hz (Studio Quality)", but it still didn't make the dropdown menu white, and i couldn't change sample rate.

Below i've added the Audio funcion descriptors:

```
    //CD
0x09,                           // Size : 9 Bytes
USB_DESCRIPTOR_CONFIGURATION,   // Configuration Descriptor (0x02)
0x10,                           // Total length in bytes of data returned
0x01,                           //      2. Byte af Total Length
0x05,                           // Number of Interfaces: 5      3 Audio + 2 Comm
0x01,                           // Configuration Value, Value to use as an argument to select this configuration
0x00,                           // iConfiguration, Index of String Descriptor describing this configuration
_DEFAULT | _SELF,               // bmAttributes, selfpowered
0xFA,                           // Maximum Power : 250 mA



    // ########          Audio Control Interface Descriptor

    //ID - Interface Descriptor
    0x09,                       // Size : 9 Bytes
    USB_DESCRIPTOR_INTERFACE,   // Interface Descriptor (0x04)
    0x00,                       // Number of Interface:                             Interface nr 0
    0x00,                       // Value used to select alternative setting
    0x00,                       // Number of Endpoints used for this interface, 0
    AUDIO_DEVICE,               // Class Code (Assigned by USB Org),                AUDIO
    AUDIOCONTROL,               // Subclass Code (Assigned by USB Org),             AUDIOCONTROL
    0x00,                       // Protocol Code (Assigned by USB Org)
    0x00,                       // Index of String Descriptor Describing this interface


        // HEADER
        0x0A,                   // Size : 10 Bytes
        CS_INTERFACE,           // CS_INTERFACE Descriptor Type
        HEADER,                 // HEADER descriptor subtype
        0x00,0x01,              // Audio Device compliant to the USB Audio specification version 1.00
        0x46,0x00,              // 64 bytes - Total number of bytes returned for the class-specific AudioControl interface descriptor.  // Includes the combined length of this descriptor header and all Unit and Terminal descriptors.
        0x02,                   // bInCollection -> Number of streaming interfaces = 2
        0x01,                   // en form for index: "AudioStreaming interface 1 belongs to this AudioControl interface."
        0x02,                   // beskriver nok streaming interface 2's index

        // INPUT_TERMINAL       ID = 1      USB Stream
        0x0B,                   // size : 12 bytes
        CS_INTERFACE,           // CS_INTERFACE Descriptor Type
        INPUT_TERMINAL,         // INPUT_TERMINAL - Descriptor subtype = 2
        INPUT_TER_USB,          // ID of this Input Terminal. // Constant uniquely identifying the Terminal within the audio function.
        USB_STREAMING,          // wTerminalType -> 0x0101 = USB streamming
        0x00,                   // bAssocTerminal -> 0x00 = No association.
        0x02,                   // bNrChannels -> 0x01 two channel.
        0x03,                   // wChannelConfig -> 0x03 = right + Left Front
        0x00,                   // iChannelNames -> 0x00 = Unused.
        0x00,                   // iTerminal -> 0x00 = Unused.

        // INPUT_TERMINAL       ID = 4      MICROPHONE
        0x0B,                   // size : 12 bytes
        CS_INTERFACE,           // CS_INTERFACE Descriptor Type
        INPUT_TERMINAL,         // INPUT_TERMINAL - Descriptor subtype
        INPUT_TER_MIC,          // bTerminalID -> ID of this Input Terminal = 4
        MICROPHONE,             // wTerminalType -> 0x0201 = Microphone
        0x00,                   // bAssocTerminal -> 0x00 = No association.
        0x02,                   // bNrChannels -> 0x01 one channel.
        0x03,                   // wChannelConfig -> 0x03 = right + Left Front
        0x00,                   // iChannelNames -> 0x00 = Unused.
        0x00,                   // iTerminal -> 0x00 = Unused.

        // OUTPUT_TERMINAL      ID = 3      SPEAKER
        0x09,                   // size : 9 Bytes
        CS_INTERFACE,           // CS_INTERFACE Descriptor Type
        OUTPUT_TERMINAL,        // OUTPUT_TERMINAL - Descriptor subtype
        OUTPUT_TER_SPEAK,       // bTerminalID -> ID of this Output Terminal = 3
        SPEAKER,                // wTerminalType -> 0x0301 = Speaker
        0x00,                   // bAssocTerminal -> 0x00 = Unused
        FEATURE_OUT,            // bSourceID -> 0x02 = From Input Terminal ID 2 = USB stream
        0x00,                   // iTerminal -> 0x00 = Unused.

        // OUTPUT_TERMINAL      ID = 6      USB Stream
        0x09,                   // Size : 9 Bytes
        CS_INTERFACE,           // CS_INTERFACE Descriptor Type
        OUTPUT_TERMINAL,        // OUTPUT_TERMINAL - Descriptor subtype
        OUTPUT_TER_USB,         // bTerminalID -> ID of this Output Terminal = 6
        USB_STREAMING,          // wTerminalType -> 0x0101 = USB streaming
        0x00,                   // bAssocTerminal -> 0x00 = Unused
        FEATURE_IN,             // bSourceID -> 0x05 = Feature Unit that sets IN features               SOURCE = 5 (Feature_IN)
        0x00,                   // iTerminal -> 0x00 = Unused.

        // FEATURE_UNIT         ID = 2
        0x0A,                   // Size : 10 Bytes
        CS_INTERFACE,           // CS_INTERFACE Descriptor Type
        FEATURE_UNIT,           // FEATURE_UNIT - Descriptor subtype
        FEATURE_OUT,            // bUnitID -> ID 2
        INPUT_TER_USB,          // bSourceID -> 0x01 = connected to Input Terminal 1                    SOURCE = 1 (Input USB)
        0x01,                   // bControlSize -> 0x01 = 1 Byte
        0x03,                   // bmaControls(n = channel nr) -> 0x03 = Mute + volume
        0x03,                   // bmaControls(n = channel nr) -> 0x03 = Mute + volume
        0x00,                   // bmaControls(n = channel nr) -> 0x00 = no master control
        0x00,                   // iFeature -> string Descriptor Unused

        // FEATURE_UNIT         ID = 5
        0x0A,                   // Size : 9 Bytes
        CS_INTERFACE,           // CS_INTERFACE Descriptor Type
        FEATURE_UNIT,           // FEATURE_UNIT - Descriptor subtype
        FEATURE_IN,             // bUnitID -> ID 5
        INPUT_TER_MIC,          // bSourceID -> 0x04 = Connected to Unit ID 4                           SOURCE = 4 (Input Mic.)
        0x01,                   // bControlSize -> 0x01 = 1 Byte
        0x03,                   // bmaControls(1) -> 0b0000011 = Mute + Volume      no. of Channels +1 = no. of bmaControls
        0x03,                   // bmaControls(2) -> 0b0000011 = Mute + Volume      no. of Channels +1 = no. of bmaControls
        0x00,                   // bmaControls(3) -> 0x00 = No controls supperted   no. of Channels +1 = no. of bmaControls
        0x00,                   // iFeature -> string Descriptor Unused


    // ########          AUDIO STREAM INTERFACE 1         OUT     SPEAKER

    //ID    // Alternate Setting 0 - 0 endpoint
    0x09,                       // Size : 9 Bytes
    USB_DESCRIPTOR_INTERFACE,   // Interface Descriptor (0x04)
    0x01,                       // bInterfaceNumber -> 0x01 Interface ID = 1
    0x00,                       // bAlternateSetting -> 0x00 = index of this interface's alternate setting
    0x00,                       // bNumEndpoints -> 0x00 = 0 Endpoints to this interface
    AUDIO_DEVICE,               // bInterfaceClass -> 0x01 = Audio Interface
    AUDIOSTREAMING,             // bInterfaceSubclass -> 0x02 = AUDIO_STREAMING
    0x00,                       // bInterfaceProtocol -> 0x00 = Unused
    0x00,                       // iInterface -> 0x00 = Unused

    //ID    // Alternate Setting 1 - 1 endpoint
    0x09,                       // Size : 9 Bytes
    USB_DESCRIPTOR_INTERFACE,   // Interface Descriptor (0x04)
    0x01,                       // bInterfaceNumber -> 0x01 Interface ID = 1
    0x01,                       // bAlternateSetting -> 0x01 = index of this interface's alternate setting
    0x01,                       // bNumEndpoints -> 0x01 = 1 Endpoints to this interface
    0x01,                       // bInterfaceClass -> 0x01 = Audio Interface
    0x02,                       // bInterfaceSubclass -> 0x02 = AUDIO_STREAMING
    0x00,                       // bInterfaceProtocol -> 0x00 = Unused
    0x00,                       // iInterface -> 0x00 = Unused

        // ASID     GENERAL
        0x07,                   // Size : 7 Bytes
        CS_INTERFACE,           // CS_INTERFACE Descriptor Type
        AS_GENERAL,             // bDescriptorSubtype -> 0x01 = GENERAL subtype
        0x01,                   // bTerminalLink -> 0x01 = The Terminal ID of the Terminal to which the endpoint of this interface is connected.
        0x01,                   // bDelay -> 0x01 = Delay (delta) introduced by the data path (see Section 3.4, ?Inter Channel Synchronization? - in Audio Devices). Expressed in number of frames.
        0x01,0x00,              // wFormatTag -> 0x0001 = PCM

        // ASID     FORMAT_TYPE
        0x0E,                   // Size : 14 Bytes
        CS_INTERFACE,           // CS_INTERFACE Descriptor Type
        FORMAT_TYPE,            // bDescriptorSubtype -> 0x02 = FORMAT_TYPE
        0x01,                   // bFormatType -> 0x01 = FORMAT_TYPE_I -> ref: A.1.1  Audio Data Format Type I Codes -> Audio Data Format Dok
        0x02,                   // bNrChannels -> 0x02 = Two channels
        BYTES_PR_SAMPLE,        // bSubFrameSize -> 0x03 = 3 bytes pr audio subframe
        BIT_RESOLUTION,         // bBitResolution -> 0x18 = 24 bit pr sample
        0x02,                   // bSamFreqType -> 0x02 = 2 sample frequencies supported
        0x00,0x7D,0x00,         // tSamFreq -> 0x7D00 = 32000 Hz
        0x80,0xBB,0x00,         // tSamFreq -> 0xBB80 = 48000 Hz

    //ED            ENDPOINT    OUT
    0x09,                       // Size : 9 Bytes
    USB_DESCRIPTOR_ENDPOINT,    // 0x05 -> ENDPOINT Descriptor Type
    0x01,                       // bEndpointAddress -> 0x01 = adress 1, OUT, -> ref 9.6.6 Endpoint -> usb_20 Dok
    0x09,                       // bmAttributes -> 0b00001001 -> Bits 0-1 = 01 = Isochronous , Bits 2-3 = 10 = Adaptive
    AUDIO_MAX_SAMPLES * sizeof ( AUDIO_PLAY_SAMPLE ), AUDIO_MAX_SAMPLES * sizeof ( AUDIO_PLAY_SAMPLE )>>8,
    0x01,                       // bInterval -> 0x01 = 1 millisecond
    0x00,                       // Unused
    0x00,                       // Unused

        //AS        ENDPOINT
        0x07,                   // Size : 7 Bytes
        CS_ENDPOINT,            // CS_ENDPOINT
        EP_GENERAL,             // bDescriptorSubtype -> 0x01 = GENERAL
        SAMPLING_FREQ_CONTROL,  // bmAttributes -> 0b00000001 = Bit 1 = 1 => Sample Freq Control is supported by this endpoint
        0x00,                   // bLockDelayUnits -> 0x00 = Indicates the units used for the wLockDelay field: 0 = Undefined
        0x00,0x00,              // the time it takes this endpoint to reliably lock its internal clock recovery circuitry.


// ########          AUDIO STREAM INTERFACE 2         IN     MICROPHONE

    //ID    // Alternate Setting 0 - 0 endpoint
    0x09,                       // Size : 9 Bytes
    USB_DESCRIPTOR_INTERFACE,   // Interface Descriptor (0x04)
    0x02,                       // bInterfaceNumber -> 0x02 Interface ID = 2
    0x00,                       // bAlternateSetting -> 0x00 = Value used to select this alternate setting for the interface identified in the prior field
    0x00,                       // bNumEndpoints -> 0x00 = 0 -> Number of endpoints used by this interface
    AUDIO_DEVICE,               // bInterfaceClass -> 0x01 = 1 = AUDIO
    AUDIOSTREAMING,             // bInterfaceSubClass -> 0x02 = AUDIO_STREAMING
    0x00,                       // bInterfaceProtocol -> 0x00 = Unused
    0x00,                       // iInterface -> 0x00 = Unused -> Index of string descriptor.

    //ID    // Alternate Setting 1 - 1 endpoint
    0x09,                       // Size : 9 Bytes
    USB_DESCRIPTOR_INTERFACE,   // Interface Descriptor (0x04)
    0x02,                       // bInterfaceNumber -> 0x02 Interface ID = 2
    0x01,                       // bAlternateSetting -> 0x01 = Value used to select this alternate setting for the interface identified in the prior field
    0x01,                       // bNumEndpoints -> 0x01 = 1 -> Number of endpoints used by this interface
    0x01,                       // bInterfaceClass -> 0x01 = 1 = AUDIO
    0x02,                       // bInterfaceSubClass -> 0x02 = AUDIO_STREAMING
    0x00,                       // bInterfaceProtocol -> 0x00 = Unused
    0x00,                       // iInterface -> 0x00 = Unused -> Index of string descriptor.

        // ASID     GENERAL
        0x07,                   // Size : 7 Bytes
        CS_INTERFACE,           // CS_INTERFACE Descriptor Type
        AS_GENERAL,             // GENERAL Descriptor
        0x06,                   // bTerminalLink -> 0x06 = The Terminal ID of the Terminal to which the endpoint of this interface is connected. = 6
        0x01,                   // bDelay -> 0x01 = Delay (delta) introduced by the data path (see Section 3.4, ?Inter Channel Synchronization? - in Audio Devices). Expressed in number of frames.
        0x01,0x00,              // wFormatTag -> 0x0001 = PCM

        // ASID     FORMAT_TYPE
        0x0E,                   // Size : 14 Bytes
        CS_INTERFACE,           // CS_INTERFACE Descriptor Type
        FORMAT_TYPE,            // bDescriptorSubtype -> 0x02 = FORMAT_TYPE
        0x01,                   // bFormatType -> 0x01 = FORMAT_TYPE_I -> ref: A.1.1  Audio Data Format Type I Codes -> Audio Data Format Dok
        0x02,                   // bNrChannels -> 0x02 = Two channels
        BYTES_PR_SAMPLE,        // bSubFrameSize -> 0x03 = 3 bytes pr audio subframe
        BIT_RESOLUTION,         // bBitResolution -> 0x18 = 24 bit pr sample
        0x02,                   // bSamFreqType -> 0x02 = 2 sample frequencies supported
        0x00,0x7D,0x00,         // tSamFreq -> 0x7D00 = 32000 Hz
        0x80,0xBB,0x00,         // tSamFreq -> 0xBB80 = 48000 Hz

    //ED            ENDPOINT        IN
    0x09,                       // Size : 9 Bytes
    USB_DESCRIPTOR_ENDPOINT,    // 0x05 -> ENDPOINT Descriptor Type
    0x82,                       // bEndpointAddress -> 0x82 = adress 2, IN, -> ref 9.6.6 Endpoint -> usb_20 Dok
    0x05,                       // bmAttributes -> 0b00000101 -> Bits 0-1 = 01 = Isochronous , Bits 2-3 = 01 = Asynchronous
    AUDIO_MAX_SAMPLES * sizeof ( AUDIO_PLAY_SAMPLE ), AUDIO_MAX_SAMPLES * sizeof ( AUDIO_PLAY_SAMPLE )>>8,
    0x01,                       // bInterval -> 0x01 = 1 millisecond
    0x00,                       // unused
    0x00,                       // unused

        //AS        ENDPOINT
        0x07,                   // Size : 7 Bytes
        CS_ENDPOINT,            // bDescriptorType -> 0x25 = CS_ENDPOINT
        EP_GENERAL,             // bDescriptorSubtype -> 0x01 = GENERAL
        SAMPLING_FREQ_CONTROL,  // bmAttributes -> 0b00000001 = Bit 1 = 1 => Sample Freq Control is supported by this endpoint
        0x00,                   // bLockDelayUnits -> 0x00 = Indicates the units used for the wLockDelay field: 0 = Undefined
        0x00,0x00,              // the time it takes this endpoint to reliably lock its internal clock recovery circuitry.
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 1):

This post is quite old but my reply maybe helpful to others facing the same difficulty.

I noticed that windows does not make changes to the installed drivers when the interface changes. You must manually uninstall the windows driver for your device and let windows reinstall it either on USB re-connection or reset of the device.

Comment: [USBDeview](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html) works well for uninstalling lots of old configurations at once